# Html.ValidationMessageFor with image and tooltip

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, unobtrusive-validation

Since few days I'm already banging my head against it, tried all ideas (nooby or not) but it seems I can't get it to work.

What I'm trying to archive is:
Instead of the original Validation message I would like to just show an icon with a jquery tooltip.
Also the solution should be easy to maintain ... means useable on every View where validation is requiered.

What I tried so far:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Password, Nothing, New With {.class = "ValWarn"})
```

CSS:

```
.ValWarn {content: url(images/Warning.png);margin: 0.1em;}
```

Result: [image 1](http://fruity.bastelpool.de/sof/prob1.png)

Problem: I cant assign the Validation message to its title.

Test #20357

```
    <div id="divhiddenval" style="display: none;">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Password)
    </div>
    @Html.PasswordFor(Function(m) m.Password)
    <div id="valdiv_@Html.IdFor(Function(m) m.Password)" style="display: inline;"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        fullValidation();
        $('form').submit(function () {
            if (! $(this).valid()) {
                fullValidation();
                return false;
            }
        });
            $('input').keydown( function () {
                singleValidation(this.id);
                tooltip();
            });

        });


        function singleValidation(_id) {
            var _err = $("span[data-valmsg-for='" + _id + "']");

            if ($(_err).text() != "") {
                $("#valdiv_" + $(_err).attr("data-valmsg-for")).html("<span class='ValWarn tooltip' title='<span class=&quot;warncolor&quot;>" + $(_err).text() + "</span>'></span>");

            } else {
                $("#valdiv_" + $(_err).attr("data-valmsg-for")).html("");
            }
        }

        function fullValidation() {
            $("#divhiddenval span[data-valmsg-for]").each(function () {
                singleValidation($(this).attr("data-valmsg-for"));
            })
            tooltip();
        }
```

Result: [shows tooltip on hover](http://fruity.bastelpool.de/sof/prob2.png)

Problem: It's kind of an overkill to call tooltip() each time. Also it does not work on the first keypress. It works when i move out of the input and move in again to type. so the keypress wont fire until it lost focus once.

Next try:
I found somewhere on the internet a ValidationHTMLMessageFor Extension. quite close but so far...
My application is globalized so I would be forced to add the image before every resourcestring as for dataanotations it only takes static strings. Also the tooltip problem wont get fixed with this.

So at all.... I cant think of any other method that would work as i want it to.
On the other hand i can not believe that Microsoft makes it that hard to style Validationmessages by our own :(

If someone please could help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK so part of the issue here is that ValidateMessageFor returns a span element containing the error message you declared in your model. Instead I would try using ValidateFor. ValidateFor will not return the error message attached to the model but will signal that validation failed for the field it is tied to which makes it a great candidate for the notification you're wanting to present to the user.

Make sure you have client validation and unobtrusive javascript enabled in your web.config along with the correct javascript files are included in the view.

web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

javascript

```
~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.­js
~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unob­trusive.min.js
```

Here's a decent reference on a similar usage you're trying to implement but using  [ValidateFor](http://raykuhnell.com/2013/05/06/asp-net-mvc-validation-messages-using-jquery-ui-tooltips/)

I forgot to add that the method I explained would do the validation unobtrusively, not having to "submit" the form. You can still get your desired result in the same manner with submitting the form using ValidateFor to flag your validation having errors and then use jQuery to access the data for input-validation-error class and data-val- attribute for the error message of your tooltip.

Comment: Good morning and thank you for sharing the link. 
Two problems i encounter with this solution.
1. What if i have multiple validation rules on a property? Lets say it is required and also have a data-val-length as well? the method, described in the link is not catching up the current error. so if I set a password with a length of 3 then the tooltip will still show the required error instead of the length error.

2. problem ... this one is most annoying... if i dont use ValidationMessageFor for all the properties i get an "unexcpected token u" from unonbstutive js. most annoying thing tbh